# Other Player's Bodies tutorial in Nier:Automata for Switch

Tags: nintendo-switch, nier-automata

Is it possible to trigger the "Other Player's Bodies" tutorial in the Nintendo Switch port of Nier:Automata?  And, if so, how can it be triggered?  It's the one tutorial I'm missing for 100% tutorial completion.

Some additional information:

- I have never seen another player's body in game, only the various android corpses that give a free plug-in chip and my own bodies after I've been killed.  I have 70 hours in the game and have acquired all five of the major endings.
- I have the network settings turned on, and they've been turned on for the vast majority of my gameplay time.  The game frequently shows the "Connecting to Network..." message, but never states whether or not it has successfully connected.  However, Ending E seems to suggest that it does work.
- I have attempted to fully turn off my Switch (not just sleep mode), and turn it back on and then immediately go searching for bodies.  This apparently helps with WiFi problems the Switch might have, but no bodies appeared.
- After all of the above, the locations I searched for bodies were in the Park Ruins where you fight Simone, the City Ruins underground cave where you fight Adam/Eve, and the corridor in the underground cave where you fight

> the secret boss Emil.

I've tried looking other places on the internet for answers, but the best I've found was other players with the Switch port who have never seen another players body (sources: [1](https://www.reddit.com/r/nier/comments/12awpsy/nier_automata_switch_other_players_bodies/), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/nier/comments/xxodt5/network_features_not_working_on_switch_version/), [3](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/371740-nier-automata-the-end-of-yorha-edition/80200971)).  I have not found anyone online who has confirmed they've successfully triggered this tutorial in the Switch port.

I greatly appreciate any assistance you can provide!